“自分” not referring back to the subject?


This particular usage of “自分のためにやっているんだ” caught my eye. I would have originally interpreted it as meaning “Don't mind it; I'm doing this for myself you see.” with “自分” referring back to the subject, which in this case is the speaker. But the context seems to imply the older brother character is doing it for the younger brother character [誠].
So is that the correct interpretation and can “自分” in this context also refer to the listener, and not necessarily refer back to the subject? which I've hitherto only seen when it's used as a subject.

In this case, 自分 does point to "myself". He's saying he's doing it for his younger brother but telling it as it was something he does for himself. However, 自分 is sometimes used as "you" in the Kansai dialect.

This 自分のためにやっているんだ does mean "I'm doing this for the sake of myself". If it doesn't make sense yet, just keep reading. I suppose the next page has an explanation regarding how making Mikoto happy will lead to the speaker's own happiness. There should be something like "(おまえが幸せそうに笑ってる姿)が唯一の俺の願いなんだ".
